# Needs Ideas - Docusign Features and its Integration With an Existing C# Project

Tags: docusignapi

I have a C# project already running. Currently my project registration form has a paragraph related to waiver conditions and then a checkbox of Yes I agree. Customer has to tick the checkbox to submit the form. I want some below mentioned changes in the existing flow:

Currently customer has to check the waiver box each time he/she submits the form (customer can submit the form for each events, as a new user or as an existing user too). I want to remove this and I want to make this waiver paragraph to be converted into a doucment where the customer can esign in bottom area of document and I can save this document at docusign end for atleast 3 - 5 years by customer id or email and so if a customer signed document already exists at my docusign account, he/she didn't had to sign the waiver form again and again.

I want ideas/suggestions from docusign experts/seniors about whether docusign offers the functionalities of:

1. signing the docusign document at client side (not at docusign website)
2. saving the signed document at docusign end by customer id/email for atleast 3-5 years.
3. from apis/webhook search whether a signed document already exists related to a specific customer id/email.
4. Option to delete/remove any specific signed document

Is this possible? If yes then how, if not then Any ideas/ any suggestions what I can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, I would suggest using elastic signing. This scenario is perfect for elastic signing assuming:

1. Only one signer.
2. No data needs to be provided by signer, all they have to do is sign.

The elastic signing API enables you to create first something called "elastic template" which everyone will sign and then for each signer - an "elastic agreement". Once a signer sigs an elastic agreement, the system remembers it, allows you to download it, and won't ask you to sign again for the same signer.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/click101/concepts/

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/how-to/create-elastic-templates/

Comment: I ran the QuickStartApp frm Docusign n I was able to create an elastic template using clickApi. there is one issue: the response I am receiving is showing the status of the newly created template as "draft" However as per docusign examples the response should have been "inactive", due to this change in response when i am moving to step 2 of activating elastic template using clickapi its giving error "Problem: You do not have an active elastic template..." can you please guide why the status was appearing as draft in response and how can i activate the elastic template? thanks

Comment: we're in the process of updating this, as this is a recent change. Which lang are you using?

Comment: if it's C#, I can show you how to do this

Comment: You should also be able to do this from the web app, by going to "Templates" and finding you elastic templates

Comment: I am using C#, can you please show how to do it?

Comment: Just do             return clickAccountApi.UpdateClickwrapVersion(accountId, clickwrapId, clickwrapVersion, clickwrapRequest);

Comment: where         public static ClickwrapRequest BuildUpdateClickwrapVersionRequest()
        {
            var clickwrapRequest = new ClickwrapRequest
            {
                Status = "active",
            };

            return clickwrapRequest;
        }

Comment: The C# code in quickstart to activate is correct, you just change status to active, but you have to specific a version in the URL

Comment: Thanks for the help, What i did is that i changed inactive to draft in GetInactiveClickwraps function and now all drafts templates are appearing and selecting anyone and activating it is also working correctly

Comment: yes, sorry about that part, which is going to be fixed soon

Comment: Inbar, Can you please answer below q's
1. If I just want to use clickapi elastic template options (eg embedding, getting list of templates, getting reponses) should I have to download whole QuickResponse code or whole SDK or is there any shorter code that will work to perform these steps?
2. How can I Authenticate and how can i get access token for my c# site automatically through code, when previous token expires. Can you share any code example?
3. Is it possible to remove this text frm template "Additionally I certify I have read and agree to Electronic Record and Signature Disclosure"?

Comment: 4. Also Can i remove the Powered by Docusign image from template footer?
5. Is there any option in ClickApi to search 4 a response by unique Id and check if that response exists or not?
6. Is there any option to download response pdf from clickApi in code?
7. Can I remove the client user id and other extra text like (DEMONSTRATION DOCUMENT ONLY PROVIDED BY DOCUSIGN ONLINE SIGNING SERVICE 999 3rd Ave, Suite 1700 • Seattle • Washington 98104 • (206) 219-0200www.docusign.com) from response pdf?
8. In template can I give a date pattern that shows date of the current day itself in given pattern

Comment: 9. On embedding template on site using inline option, is ther any option to get and check if and when the user agrees (signs) the document and perform a custom event through code?
10. Is there any option to remove a response saved on docusign, automatically after a specific time (for eg: 1 year) or to remove a specific response by code from clickApi?
11. Can you please tell me which paid package/plan/version will be best suitable for creating and embedding elastic templates and saving response for a specific time period on docusign using clickApi?

Comment: Q1 - There's no need to download the whole quickstart just to do that, you can take the Click code example into your code

Comment: Question 7 - The Demo note is because you're using Demo, you need a paid account in production to use it for real and not see this note

Comment: 9. The answer is yes

Comment: q2 - you can use JWT and then one time consent and you can always get access tokens w/o having to authenticate again

Comment: q3 - no, this is a legal requirement, I'm not a lawyer, but for legal reasons we require this text

Comment: q4, no, you can probably do that using javascript, but that's not something we support

Comment: q6, yes, you can do that, I can show you, maybe ask a separate thread here on SO as this is getting too lengthy and too many questions in a single thread which is hard to manage

Comment: OK thanks here is the link to new thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76262773/docusign-integration-in-c-sharp-need-help-in-particular-issue