# Docusign integration in C#

Tags: docusignapi

I have a C# site in which I want to let my customers sign a Terms and conditions document once in a year and I want to save the signed document with customer Id at my end or other secure/accessible place for 1 year.

To meet the above scenario I have decided to use Docusign. I am creating an Elastic template at Docusign and then embedding that document on my C# site using ClickApi. I have a few questions/issues that are mentioned below:

1. Currently the Elastic Templates are giving the option of checkbox button and not eSignature option. Is there any way my customer can sign an esignature and not just checking the "I agree" checkbox?
2. How can I Authenticate and how can I get access token for my c# site automatically through code, when previous token expires? Is there example code available?
3. Is there any option in ClickApi to search for a signed document (response) by unique (customer) Id and check if that response exists or not?
4. Is there any option to download signed document (response pdf) from ClickApi in code?
5. On embedding template on site using inline option, is there any option to get and check if and when the user agrees (signs) the document and perform a custom event through code? How? Is an example available?
6. Is there any option to remove a signed document (response) saved on Docusign, automatically after a specific time (for eg: 1 year) or to remove a specific response by code from clickApi?
7. In Elastic template content can I give a date pattern (for eg: d/m/y) that shows date of the current day in given format itself when embedded on my site?
8. Which paid package/plan/version of Docusign or any other will be best suitable that provides all above functionalities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not at the moment, elastic templates are not yet full eSignature.
2. Use JWT, that allows you to impersonate a user with a single consent once and never have to log in again.
3. Yes, the createHasAgreed endpoint will tell you the answer to this.
4. Yes, you can use the getClickwrapsAgreements() endpoint for this.

Comment: Is there any other option to get esignature without using elastic templates?
Also can you please answer remaining questions from 5-8

Comment: Yes, sure, you can use eSignature, not sure what you mean, elastic is a specialized case of eSignature, not regular eSignature.

Comment: sorry but my question is that currently I am creating an elastic template and then embedding it on my site, however, elastic template isn't offering esignature option, so is there any other option in DocuSign in which I can create a template and embed it on my site and in that document on my site, my customer can sign it too and after signature the signed response saves on docusign? if yes can you share me the name of the option and any example code.
Also please if you can answer my above remaining questions from 5-8?

Comment: no, there isn't for now, you'll need to use eSignature and not elastic template. So that's why I didn't answer 5-8, because it's irrelevant for you as you should not be using elastic templates .

Comment: ok any example code in which esignature is used?

Comment: If you downloaded the C# quickstart, it's all in there, just pick one that is called "Request a signature through your app (embedded signing)"

Comment: The code for this is in https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/EmbeddedSigningCeremony.cs